# Read bytes of a PNG in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, png

I want to read the bytes of a PNG, and modify them. I already tried this code:

```
import codecs
ed = input("Would you like to encode or decode?\n(e/d)> ")
image = input("What image would you like to use?\n> ")
if(ed == 'e'):
    imagef = codecs.open(image, encoding = "hex")
    imagel = imagef.read()
    img = imagel.decode('hex')
    print(img)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Would you like to encode or decode?
(e/d)> e
What image would you like to use?
> i.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    imagel = imagef.read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 700, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 503, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 25, in decode
    return hex_decode(input, errors)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 19, in hex_decode
    return (binascii.a2b_hex(input), len(input))

binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: hex is not binary. You need to read the image in binary mode. Don't use `codecs`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I don't know how to read a file in binary mode. When reading it without codecs (using open), I get this error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    imagel = imagef.read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: But now you are using a decoder *again*. (Python's default decoder, designed to read UTF8 text.) A PNG is not "encoded text", in any form, way, or meaning. Read up about reading *bytes*. Then – and *only* then, if you can succesfully read those bytes – read up on the PNG specifications. Pay particular attention to the parts that explain the Flate compression, it is tough even for more experienced programmers than you. And then, give up and use a library.

Answer (score 2):

step back - your assumptions are not correct

png files don't have "hexadecimal content" - they have bytes - "hexadecimal" is not what you think, it is just another way of representing a number.

Your code is not fixable because it doesn't make any sense in first place - there is nothing to decode.

Hexadecimal is used by programmers as a convenience because each hex digit 
 can represent 4 bits so it takes only two hexadecimal digits to represent a byte. However this is just representation.

EDIT:

From the comments it seems what you want is to add binary data to the end of the file:

```
message = 'Hello World!'

with open(image, 'ab') as f: # open the file for appending, binary mode
    f.write(bytes(8))  # write 8 null bytes to the file
    f.write(message.encode('utf-8'))  # add the message, encoded to bytes
                                      # by using the utf-8 encoding
```

Then to read again the message:

```
with open(image, 'rb') as f: # open the file in read binary mode
    data = f.read() # read the bytes from the file to a variable

pos = data.find(bytes(8)) # locate the 8 null bytes
message = data[pos + 8:].decode('utf-8')  # decode the message
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Is there a way of reading/modifying the bytes of a PNG in python?

Comment: @JohnSmith sure! But how? Why? What do you want to modify?

Comment: I had an assignment to hide messages in an image. My idea was to add eight null bytes to the end, then encode a message in hexadecimal - or bytes, I guess. Then write a program to look for eight null bytes and from there start decoding the message.